# How do you add a new list to the bottom of the list?

Tags: python

I have a couple of lists presented in vertical format and i am trying to add a new list to the bottom of it but whenever i try to do that i often got the new list being appended within the lists and not bottom of it

i parsed the lists in to names and heights variables:

```
for data in f:
    drawingdata = data.split()
    names = drawingdata[0]
    heights = drawingdata[1]
    names_list = names.strip('][').split(',')
```

Here is the example of the couple of lists:

```
Tom 1.65
Sharon 1.55
James 1.71
Jason 1.66
Jane 1.60
```

when i print the names_list variable:

```
['Tom']
['Sharon']
['James']
['Jason']
['Jane']
```

i wanted the outcome to be:

```
['Tom']
['Sharon']
['James']
['Jason']
['Jane']
['John']
```

I tried using append() function but it didn't work out well here is the outcome of the append function

```
['Tom', 'John']
['Sharon','John']
['James',"John']
['Jason','John']
['Jane','John']
```

I don't know how to do it, please use basic functions no imports as this is from a tests i did they did not require imports

Comment: How does the list of lists look like exactly? As of now these are 5 separate lists. Or are you even referring to Python lists?

Comment: i am referring to python lists. i actually parsed this list from another .txt file and seprated into two variables names and heights with names to strings and heights to floats and it looked like this Tom 1.65
Sharon 1.55
James 1.71
Jason 1.66
Jane 1.60 just vertical

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56608854/edit) your question and include details there. FYI, a list of lists look like: `[[a,..],[b,..]]`.

Comment: oops probably i was wrong i think i meant was a couple of lists and adding new lists to the bottom of that couple of lists

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
list_1 = [['Tom'], ['Sharon'], ['James'], ['Jason'], ['Jane']]
list_2 = [['John'], ['Eliza']]
new_list = list_1 + list_2
for i in new_list:
    ['Tom']
    ['Sharon']
    ['James'] 
    ['Jason']
    ['Jane']
    ['John']
    ['Eliza']
```

Comment: actually i parse this list from another file and seperated in to two variable with names to strings and heights to floats here is the example of the list just that its in vertical format Tom 1.65
Sharon 1.55
James 1.71
Jason 1.66
Jane 1.60 also when i print out the variables names the list just comes out in that format u saw above

Comment: probably i was wrong sorry i meant that its a couple of lists into one variable and i am trying to add a new data to the bottom of the that couple of lists

Comment: you should edit your question and give more precise objects. hard to help you without having more.

Comment: sorry now i redited the question can u help to look into it again?

Comment: print drawingdata, names, etc... It's not enough. Do you want to join all these list (if they are list) together? Is that right? What are ther types? Are you sure it's list and not string?

Comment: i just want to add John to the bottom of the names_list variable

Comment: names_list is not a list, it's a string. what's the result of ```type(names_list)```?

Comment: List i checked alr

Comment: you didn't. Check again, a list has not split() nor strip() method and you did ```names_list = names.strip('][').split(',')```. It's a ```str```.

Comment: oh that the strip and split method was applied to names variable as names is a string and i did check i enter type(names_list) it gave me the outcome List

Comment: sorry i didn't provide enough code thanks for your help and sorry for wasting your time